# DrawRect fits 4" screen, but runs off the bottom of 3.5"

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect

Ive Created a DrawRect that fits the screen perfectly when running on a 4" screen. but when applied to a 3.5" the size changes and cant be constrained. Is there a way i can maintain its shape on both? Below is my code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect rrect = CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 515);
    CGFloat radius = 7;

    CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rrect), midx = CGRectGetMidX(rrect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rrect);
    CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rrect), midy = CGRectGetMidY(rrect), maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rrect);

    // Start at 1
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minx, midy);
    // Add an arc through 2 to 3
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, miny, midx, miny, radius);
    // Add an arc through 4 to 5
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, radius);
    // Add an arc through 6 to 7
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, radius);
    // Add an arc through 8 to 9
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, maxy, minx, midy, radius);

    // Close the path
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1.0);

    // Fill & stroke the path
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

Comment: surely your `rrect`'s height value needs to change depending on the screen height? at the moment i dont see any code to factor in the screen height changing...

Comment: The Shape fits on a 4 inch screen perfectly, and also a 3.5 if its altered. i want to set a constraint to do this automatically? @Fonix

Comment: well your `rrect` is set in code so you wont be able to make it constraint based unless you base it on a views frame that does have a constraint maybe